# can you spot a problem in this code

Tags: jquery

anybody seeing a problem in this code....firebug is telling me  ) is missing

```
$('#addschool').dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    buttons:{
        "add school":function(){alert(school added);},
        cancel:function(){$(this).dialog("close");}
    }
});
$(this).dialog('open');
```

Comment: You *need* to start accepting answers to all your previous questions. [Here is how to do it.](http://privat.rejbrand.se/howtoaccept.html)

Comment: David, please accept some answers to your previous questions.  See the FAQ here:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should be `alert('school added');`, not `alert(school added);`

Don't forget the quotes :)

Answer (score 2):

You had missing `}` and missing quotes, this passes jslint now:

```
$('#addschool').dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    buttons:{
        "add school": function(){
            alert("school added");
        },
        cancel:function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$(this).dialog('open');
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. First attempt at editing the question didn't help much. It looks better now

Answer (score 0):

I think 
alert(school added); should be alert("school added");?